# Pivot field disappearing when running macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to create a pivot table. My code works but the output is not perfect. The output seems to be correct until I add the data field. When I add the data field of count of 'check', it removes it from being one of the pivot fields. Does anybody have any idea why this is?

```
Sub Create_Pivot()
Dim PCache As PivotCache, LastRow As Long, pt As PivotTable

 Worksheets("X Data").Activate
 Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
 Sheets("X Results").Select

 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=Range("E7"), TableName:="X Pivot")
     
     ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
     With pt.PivotFields("Counterparty Desc")
         .Orientation = xlRowField
         .Position = 1
     End With
     With pt.PivotFields("Check")
         .Orientation = xlRowField
         .Position = 2
     End With

     pt.AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "X Pivot").PivotFields("Check"), "Count of Check", xlCount

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you do the same thing manually in excel?  Does the row field also disappear when you add it as a data field?

Comment: When I do it manually I use the pivot table field list and drag the fields into the correct areas ie. rows/values. It doesn't disappear when I do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem I solved it by re arranging the order I added the data field. I added the count of check data field before adding the field lists.